# How can I update my database field with a new value plus the original value in database

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to update a field in my database by adding an amount to the value inside that field. My temporary fix is to retrieve the original value from the database with a DataReader but I want to avoid using it. This is my sql statement:

```
OleDbCommand updateBankBalance = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Users SET [Bank Balance] = @accountIncome WHERE Username = '" + getUsername() + "'", conn);
updateBankBalance.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountIncome", rAmount.ToString("0.##") + "VALUE IN DATABASE");
updateBankBalance.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note:

- "VALUE IN DATABASE" is the original value in the field. Is there someway to call it without using a DataReader?
- rAmount is declared as a decimal type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE Users SET [Bank Balance] = @accountIncome + [Bank Balance] WHERE Username = ?
```

If you are using older version of sql then you may use the Concat function like:

```
UPDATE Users SET [Bank Balance] = Concat(@accountIncome,[Bank Balance]) WHERE Username = ?
```

Comment: The first one worked for me. Thank you very much I appreciate it!

Comment: If this answer helped you then please accept it to help the community.